# How to extend query table for reviews of people I follow with user details

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to create a Django project, and currently I have three models in use: the standard Django User, Review and Follow, given below:

```
class Review(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text_content = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    movie_rating = models.IntegerField()


class Follow(models.Model):
    following = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="following")
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follower")
```

What I want to get as a result is given user as a input, get all the reviews of people I follow. I used the following command `Review.objects.filter(author__following__follower=user)`, and it gives me the user_id, text_content and movie_rating, but I'm not sure how to extend this table to add some things from the User model, such as first_name and last_name.

Comment: did you check out select_related?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it for adding new rows to the queryset, I was thinking about using  union but couldn't figured a way to set it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
reviews = Review.objects.filter(author__following__follower=user).select_related('author')
```

When you want to render first_name, try:

```
{% for review in reviews %}

{{review.author.first_name}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to make it as an API with the Django Rest Framework, but instead of just sending the user id, I also want to send the user details, and was trying to think if there is easier way instead of iterating in all reviews and manually adding the user data.